# jQuery: check what DIV from group of DIVs with classes that contain the same part in name has some attribute

Tags: jquery, css

How could I detect if only one DIV of any number of ones with predefined part of their class name has certain style parameter?

For example I have the following HTML:

```
<style>
    .number_one, .number_two {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<div class="number_one">Number 1</div>
<div class="number_two">Number 2</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".number_one").click(function() {
            jQuery(".number_one").css("display", "none");
        });
        jQuery(".number_two").click(function() {
            jQuery(".number_two").css("display", "none");
        });
    })
<script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpwuhwmb/) (but it really does nothing other than changing DIV's parameters)

How could I, for example, prevent any action taken against the only DIV that is still visible, assuming I could have unlimited number of divs, but all of them will always share **`number_`** as part of their class name.

Comment: Some questions to better understand: 1-you need to understand if there's only a DIV visible ? 2- all the divs have different class, but the classes names start always with 'number' ? 3- You can change this design ?

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of `jQuery("div:not([style])")` since only clicked `<div>`s would have the `style` attribute

Comment: @Massimo: 1 - only one DIV with specific part in class name has specific CSS attribute; 2 - not exactly start with, but share; 3 - design of what?

Comment: @YKKY: I specified what I meant with 'design'  in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this CSS selector:

```
jQuery('div[class^="number_"]:visible').length
```

To track the number of visible `<div>`s where their class begins with `number_`. If you use a generic click handler you can check that the count of visible `<div>`s is more than 1 and only allow a `<div>` to be hidden on this condition.

```js
jQuery('div[class^="number_"]').on('click', function() {
  if (jQuery('div[class^="number_"]:visible').length > 1) {
    jQuery(this).css('display', 'none')
  }
  console.log(jQuery('div[class^="number_"]:visible').length + ' divs left');
});
```

```css
.number_one,
.number_two,
.number_three {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number_one">Number 1</div>
<div class="number_two">Number 2</div>
<div class="number_three">Number 3</div>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But what if classes names would look like **`SharedPrefix_VariablePart_SharedSuffix`** or any other combination of constant and variable parts? Let's say only one variable part to simplify the question.

Comment: In that case you would look at using multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the JQuery selector and allow more flexibility (and avoid questions on how the *number* classes are named), here  is my solution proposal. Well, really is a variation of Robin's one.

The idea (the design change I mentioned in my comment) is that all those DIVs could have also an additional class name 'number' (or whatever), common to all of them, which may be added in the HTML.

This allow the possibility of still specifying the *SharedPrefix_VariablePart_SharedSuffix* classes with their own css properties and without the need of making complex selectors on JQuery.

In the case this is applicable, the code can be as follows.

```js
jQuery('div.number').on('click', function() {
  if (jQuery('div.number:visible').length > 1) {
    jQuery(this).css('display', 'none')
  }
  console.log(jQuery('div.number:visible').length + ' divs left');
});
```

```css
.number_one {
  /*specific attrs of number_one here*/
}

.number_two {
  /*specific attrs of number_two here*/
}

.number_three {
  /*specific attrs of number_three here*/
}

.number {
  /*common attrs of number class to apply to all divs*/
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number number_one">Number 1</div>
<div class="number number_two">Number 2</div>
<div class="number number_three">Number 3</div>
```